# ISO 19115 metadata element gmd:credit

Tags: metadata, iso-19115, iso-19139

Trying to find details for a ISO element.

We looking for a place to put a formatted citation that users of a content management system include in a dataset description. These citations are in reference to a published papers.

We have the general details of the dataset (title, author detail(s), abstract), these would be put into the citation element.

We could repeat a the MD_datasetInfo/gmd:citation, but the citation is not fielded, it's as input by the user using what they see as a standard citation reference.

I am thinking that the appropriate MD_datasetInfo fields are citation, or suppliemental information.

If I look in the ISO 19139 XML schema, there is no annotation of what citation is intended for.

So, what is appropriate content to put in gmd:credit element?

http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/niem21/t-gmd_MD_DataIdentification_Type.html

Answering myself, since I guess questions about actual ISO geographic metadata specifications are out of scope.

> Credit - recognition of those who contributed to the resource(s)

Found on pdf page 55 in retired OGC document:    [The OpenGIS Abstract Specification: Topic 11: OpenGIS(tm) Metadata (ISO/TC 211 DIS 19115)](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=1094&version=1) (may require OGC member access)

Comment: Probably in the ISO spec:Found answer in   retired document "The OpenGIS Abstract Specification: Topic 11: OpenGIS(tm) Metadata (ISO/TC 211 DIS 19115)"

Answer (score 1):

> Credit - recognition of those who contributed to the resource(s)

Found on pdf page 55 in retired OGC document: The OpenGIS Abstract Specification: Topic 11: OpenGIS(tm) Metadata (ISO/TC 211 DIS 19115) (may require OGC member access)

Credit is not how to credit the resource, therefore the supplementalInformation field is more appropriate for the text of a referenced citation.